# How to get mean of the values of one column based on the similarity of the corresponds values in another columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I would be thankful if someone tell me how to do the task bellow. Suppose that I have a dataframe in python as follows:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A 2001    2    5
1    A 2001    2    4
2    A 2001    3    6
3    A 2002    4    5
4    B 2001    2    9
5    B 2001    2    4
6    B 2001    2    3
7    B 2001    3   95
```

I want to get the mean of the col4 if the corresponds values in col1, col2, and col3 are the same and then get rid of the rows with the repeated values in the first 3 columns. For example, the values of the col1, col2, col3 i the two first column are same, so, we want to eliminate one of them and update the value of col4 as the mean of 5 and 4.  Te result should be:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A 2001    2 4.55
1    A 2001    3    6
2    A 2002    4    5
3    B 2001    2 5.33
4    B 2001    3   95
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` to group `'col1'` and `'col2'` and `'col3'`, then get mean of the `'col4'` column:

```
print(df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'],as_index=False)['col4'].mean())
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3       col4
0    A  2001     2   4.500000
1    A  2001     3   6.000000
2    A  2002     4   5.000000
3    B  2001     2   5.333333
4    B  2001     3  95.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Now, if we have col5 and we want to do the same  thing for col4 and col5. How could we do such a task in the same time?

Comment: @user2356563 Maybe: `print(df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'],as_index=False)[['col4','col5']].mean())`

Comment: Thank again, It works. My last question is: if we have col1, col2,col3, col4 and we do mean groupby on only col3. Now, how can we keep all rows and also col4?

Comment: @user2356563 Ya mean: `print(df.groupby(['col1','col2','col4'],as_index=False)['col3'].mean())`